# TCP socket: Blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: multithreading, select, tcp, blocking, recv

I am writing a PC application that will connect with TCP to multiple micro-controller boards. The micro-controller boards are listening and the PC app connecting to each of them as a client.

There can be up to up to about 50 boards depending on configuration, and it is not clear to me if it is best to create all these sockets as blocking in individual threads waiting at recv() or make the sockets non-blocking and use select() to check for incoming data one socket at the time.

So is up to 50 threads of blocking recv() OK, or is it better to check one socket at the time with select()?

Info: Data is almost entirely coming from the micro-controller boards and the rate can vary from essentially nothing to max. of the network.

Thanks...

Comment: If all 50 devices decide to saturate the network simultaneously then using 50 threads will put a lot of strain on the system. But if that's unlikely to happen only a few of the devices will be active simultaneously then threads will be a good way to go. Especially if the devices will be handled individually and you won't have to share resources or messages between the threads.

Comment: And of course there's also the hybrid solution, with using a few threads each using non-blocking sockets and `select`. Or using non-blocking sockets and `select` and pass of incoming message processing to a thread-pool. Or even using *blocking* sockets with `select` and pass of the actual receiving (and processing) to a thread-pool.

Comment: It is likely that all 50 devices occasionally decide to saturate the network. Indeed it will for sure happen during the customer acceptance test.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all solution. Going for the threads will allow you to develop faster. Going for an event-based solution will allow the code to run faster. This should be mostly a costs estimation decision. Do not worry too much about having 50 threads, it will work. But if you have very high-bandwidth connection, it might be slow.

Comment: is the data processing independant? I assume you do not read the stream from the socket just for the sake of it. I would base my decision on what you do with the data afterwards.